# Prestashop webservice DELETE categories remove_associated

Tags: prestashop

In prestashop there is an option that asks you if you want to remove all the products in the category you want to remove, do you know which is the way with the API?

https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/webservice/tutorials/prestashop-webservice-lib/delete-resource/

```
<?php
try {
    $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice('http://example.com/', 'ZR92FNY5UFRERNI3O9Z5QDHWKTP3YIIT', false);

    $id = 2;
    $webService->delete([
        'resource' => 'customers',
        'id' => $id, // Here we use hard coded value but of course you could get this ID from a request parameter or anywhere else
    ]);
    echo 'Customer with ID ' . $id . ' was successfully deleted' . PHP_EOL;
} catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $e) {
    echo 'Error:' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

In its web site it only shows an example to remove categories.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate on products and delete. Example for 1 language shop, 10000 products catalog:

```
    $products = Product::getProducts(1, 0, 10000, 'id_product', 'DESC', $id_category_to_remove);

    $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice($yourUri, $yourKey, false);

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $webService->delete([
            'resource' => 'products',
            'id' => $product['id_product'],
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: It is not direct, but it is a solution, thank you.